# GWT Header CheckBox requires two clicks to fire setValue, after changing its value programatically

Tags: gwt, checkbox, datagrid, celltable

I have a GWT DataGrid, and a CheckBox in the Header to select/deselect all rows in the grid.

The code for the CheckBox Header is as follows:

```
    private class CheckboxHeader extends Header<Boolean> implements HasValue<Boolean> {

    private boolean checked;
    private HandlerManager handlerManager;

    /**
     * An html string representation of a checked input box.
     */
    private final SafeHtml INPUT_CHECKED = SafeHtmlUtils.fromSafeConstant("<input type=\"checkbox\" tabindex=\"-1\" checked/>");
    /**
     * An html string representation of an unchecked input box.
     */
    private final SafeHtml INPUT_UNCHECKED = SafeHtmlUtils.fromSafeConstant("<input type=\"checkbox\" tabindex=\"-1\"/>");

    @Override
    public void render(Context context, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
        if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(this.getValue())) {
            sb.append(INPUT_CHECKED);
        } else {
            sb.append(INPUT_UNCHECKED);
        }
    };

    public CheckboxHeader() {
        super(new CheckboxCell(true, false));
        checked = true;
    }

    // This method is invoked to pass the value to the CheckboxCell's render method
    @Override
    public Boolean getValue() {
        return checked;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element elem, NativeEvent nativeEvent) {
        int eventType = Event.as(nativeEvent).getTypeInt();
        if (eventType == Event.ONCHANGE) {
            nativeEvent.preventDefault();
            // use value setter to easily fire change event to handlers
            setValue(!checked, true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public HandlerRegistration addValueChangeHandler(ValueChangeHandler<Boolean> handler) {
        return ensureHandlerManager().addHandler(ValueChangeEvent.getType(), handler);
    }

    @Override
    public void fireEvent(GwtEvent<?> event) {
        ensureHandlerManager().fireEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(Boolean value) {
        setValue(value, true);
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(Boolean value, boolean fireEvents) {
        checked = value;
        if (fireEvents) {
            ValueChangeEvent.fire(this, value);
        }
    }

    private HandlerManager ensureHandlerManager() {
        if (handlerManager == null) {
            handlerManager = new HandlerManager(this);
        }
        return handlerManager;
    }
}
```

So, I add the Header to the grid, and I add a `ValueChangeHandler` to it to do the actual selecting/deselecting of individual CheckBox cells in every row of the grid. This all works.

Every `CheckBoxCell` has a Field Updater, and on every update it loops through every item in the grid to see if they are all checked, and update the header check box. If at least one is unchecked, the header checkbox will be unchecked. I call `setValue()` on the header check box, and after that I call `redrawHeaders()` on the entire grid. This also works.

What doesn't work is - after changing the "state" of the header check box programatically, it takes two clicks for it to fire it's internal setValue again, and therefore trigger my handler. And what's even funnier - the first click *does* change the state of the check box, but it just doesn't fire the event.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you constructing the CheckboxCells themselves? I ran into a similar issue with a column of checkboxes "eating" clicks, and the solution was to call `CheckboxCell cell = new CheckboxCell(true,true)` and then pass that cell into the constructor of the column.

Comment: Forgot to mention, already tried that... and pretty much every combination of those two booleans. Always takes two clicks to fire the event, even though the checkbox itself does change its state.

Comment: For what it's worth, we've implemented a Checkbox column with a header that selects / deselects all elements by doing:

`CheckboxCell cell = new CheckboxCell(true,true);`
`Column<C, Boolean> checkColumn = new Column<C, Boolean>`, overriding getValue(C) to return `cellTable.isSelected(object)`.

    checkColumn.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<C, Boolean>(){
    @Override
    public void update(int index, C object, Boolean value) {
        cellTable.setSelected(object, value);
    }
    });

Comment: Ahhh, the whole time I was passing (true, true) to the checkbox in the header, but forgot to check the one in the actual column... Sorry for that, it's working now, thank you!